# If using a property in a for loop condition, does it make sense to store the property in a local variable?

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop, memory, memory-management

Simple and small idea which probably does not affect much. If you're iterating over an array manually, say like this simple example:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < myArr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myArr[i]);
        }
```

Does it make sense to store myArr.Length locally? Like this:

```
        int myArrLen = myArr.Length
        for (int i = 0; i < myArrLen; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myArr[i]);
        }
```

Does it take any extra amount of work to access myArr.Length compared to the local variable myArrLen? Does it have to make this memory access every iteration of the for loop, or will it store myArr.Length locally automatically? Could you notice the difference if the array had say 100,000 or 1,000,000 members?

Comment: In `for (int i = 0; i < myArrLen; i++)` `myArr.Length` is cached. It's no need to store it on your own.

Comment: @Alex is right, and also you could try testing and figure out the answer. Make sure NOT to include the `Console.WriteLine()` in your test code as that can dramatically slow down performance.

Comment: @Alex Gotcha, that makes sense. If the array is especially large, or the program asynchronous, is there a concern that myArr.Length could fall out of cache?

Comment: `new object[int.MaxValue]` gave me `OutOfMemoryException`. I have 16 Gb RAM.

Comment: `Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), long.MaxValue);` gives `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Arrays larger than 2GB are not supported.`

Comment: @Alex so you're saying no because the system limits arrays to be such a size that they can always be cached entirely?

Comment: I don't know if this limitation can't be worked around. Are you sure you need so much memory?

Comment: I think he means that the end-of-range value for the loop is cached, not the elements of the array.